# Confused about the term 'Bourgeoisie'!

Tags: economy, communism, socialism, capitalism, social-class

Bourgeoisie is defined by,

> the middle class, typically with reference to its perceived materialistic values or conventional attitudes

As refer to [Google define](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20%20bourgeoisie),
[image]

Here, I see it actually means the **middle-class** people instead of **upper class**. However, when I watch debates between capitalists and communists/socialists, I find the problem of Capitalism is often referred as the clash/difference between social classes (Bourgeoisie vs. Proletariat). It is often assumed that the classes are upper rich class vs. lower working class. But, today I saw the definition somehow excluded the **upper class** (!). Why is the discussions then always between *middle-class vs. lower class* instead of *upper class vs. lower class*? What am I missing here?

Why did Karl Marx use a term representing middle class instead of upper rich class? Any background?

Comment: Read that definition carefully.  Karl Marx didn't use a term that included the middle class: "(in Marxist contexts) the capitalist class..." Marx, of course, typically wrote in a Marxist context.  This question might be a better fit for the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) site.  In political contexts, *bourgeoisie* means one thing, and Mr. Wrigley has provided a good explanation of this.  But there are other contexts where the term can have other meanings.  EL&U can cover those other contexts better.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123941/discussion-on-question-by-sazzad-hissain-khan-confused-about-the-term-bourgeois).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page for Bourgeoisie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourgeoisie) is informative, and worth the read.

Strictly speaking, there was no equivalent of middle, upper, or lower classes (in the modern usage of the terms) prior to perhaps the 17th century. The bourgeoisie were the wealthiest segment of commoners under feudal aristocracies, all the way back to the 11th century: tradesmen, merchants, manufacturers, and the like, who developed a certain amount of social and economic power under the guild system. In that era, there were:

- Feudal (titled) aristocrats, who owned land and earned money through rent and taxation
- Agricultural peasants, who had no political status and owed fealty to the feudal lord who owned the land that they tilled
- The bourgeoisie, who had a certain freedom as citizens within urban areas
- The beginnings of the proletariat, who had a similar relationship to the bourgeoise that peasants had to the landed aristocracy

In the Marxist view, the industrial revolution wasn't merely a technological revolution; it was a political and social revolution as well. The shift from a primarily agricultural society (in which the landed aristocracy owned the means of agricultural production) to a primarily industrial society (in which the bourgeoisie owned the means of industrial production) shifted the bourgeoise into a position of power equivalent to the old aristocracy, while the rural peasantry left the farms and transformed itself into the urban proletariat. That urban proletariat then conceptually divided itself into lower, middle, and upper classes, representing different statuses of employment by the bourgeoise.

The bourgeoisie themselves were never lower, middle, or upper class; they became the owning (capitalist) class, set off from and above the lower, middle, and upper classes  of workers.

The capitalist class has done a wonderful job obscuring its own existence, trying to make it appear as though it is merely the nose-bleed section of the upper middle class, and that anyone can work their way up to be part of that modernized bourgeoise. But it still carries that protectionist 'guild' mentality, where the interests and welfare of the class come first and foremost. Thinking of the bourgeoisie as middle or upper class is at best mistaken, and at worst disinformation.

Comment: "Thinking of the bourgeoise as middle or upper class is at best mistaken, and at worst disinformation." Depends on your definition of "upper class", IMO.

Comment: While you are right in a Marxist context, linguistically speaking words can have different meanings in different contexts. The meaning of "bourgeoisie" as meaning middle class seems IMO to be obviously derived from the feudal meaning by analogy, where the bourgeoisie functioned as a "middle" class between aristocrats and peasants.

Comment: The most important sentence in that wiki link: *In the 18th century, before the French Revolution (1789–99), in the French feudal order [bourgeois] identified the rich men and women who were members of the urban and rural Third Estate – the common people of the French realm, who violently deposed the absolute monarchy of the Bourbon King Louis XVI, his clergy, and his aristocrats in the French Revolution of 1789–1799.* ***Hence, since the 19th century, the term "bourgeoisie" usually is politically and sociologically synonymous with the ruling upper-class of a capitalist society.[6]***

Comment: The last paragraph seems to be your (rather one-sided and very propaganda-sounding) opinion, you might want to either clarify according to whom, or remove it as it doesn't really add anything to the otherwise fine answer.

Comment: @vsz: Not only is that last paragraph opinion, it is opinion that has been proven false by experimental evidence.

Comment: @jamesqf could you provide a source on that? It seems quite interesting, and I would like to learn more about that.

Comment: I agree that the Wikipedia article is useful, and slightly disappointed that the OP gave excessive weight to a dictionary definition without referring to Wp for more extended discussion and context.

Comment: @Ekadh Singh: Certainly.  My own life, for instance.  Or most of the founders of successful tech companies.

Comment: @jamesqf You know that the plural of anecdote is not evidence, right?

Comment: *...the interests and welfare of the [bourgeoise] class come first and foremost...*. This is at best muddled thinking. There is no [Secret Council of Capitalism](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheOmniscientCouncilOfVagueness) telling members of this class what to do, and in fact the tendency of capitalists to immiserate the other classes is [evidence of this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons), because if nobody else has money then who is going to buy the stuff that the capitalists make? Ideologically capitalists *don't believe* in class solidarity.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: you've conflated the term 'class' with the term 'cabal'. For the most part feudal lords were intent on killing each other and acquiring each other's land — there was no 'secret council' of feudal lords, either — but they all still had a vested interest in keeping their labor force (and erstwhile cannon fodder) suppressed and obedient. Capitalists don't have to like or cooperate with each other to be considered a class; They are class because they share the same source of wealth — labor value extracted from laborers — and a vested interest in maximizing that wealth.

Comment: @TedWrigley You're missing my point: the quote I'm criticizing said that the bourgeoise put *class* interests first and foremost; in other words capitalists do things to benefit *other capitalists* out of some misplaced sense of duty, and presumably in response to some kind of programme or ideology. This is not the case: a fundamental principle of capitalism is that you look out for yourself. And there were councils of feudal lords, but they didn't need to be secret.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: Perhaps bad phrasing on my part, but regardless the statement is fundamentally true. Just look at US anti-trust laws, which are designed to keep companies from banding together to fix prices, fix wages, or otherwise circumvent normal competition in order to increase mutual profits. You can say that the fundamental principle of capitalism is 'looking out for oneself' (which is quite debatable, mind you), but you have to acknowledge that sometimes the best way to 'look out for oneself' is to band together with other like-minded individuals against a common foe.

Comment: @TedWrigley Yes, but any such cartel is always temporary, contingent and limited to a small group or single industry. E.g. the Phoebus cartel over-charged everyone for electric lights that quickly burned out, including other capitalists who needed to illuminate their factories.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: And yet, there's near perfect agreement among capitalists that wages, benefits, and pro-labor or pro-consumer regulations should be kept to an absolute minimum. You seem to be arguing from a Libertarian free-market ideology that (for its merits) doesn't have much practical application to the world.

Comment: @jamesqf nonsense. The existence of counterexamples does not disprove a widespread tendency (https://www.vox.com/2016/5/18/11691818/barone-mocetti-florence). Anyway, most high-performing tech CEOs come from already-rich families

Comment: @llama: The existence of counterexamples (and many of them!) is sufficient to prove the falsity of any claim.  And can you support the idea that people making lots of money in tech come from wealthy families?  Note that I didn't limit it to just CEOs, since the qualities needed to be a successful tech person are different from those of a good manager.  (See e.g. the Peter Principle, or just about any Dilbert cartoon :-))  Re your example, note that Florence (and indeed, all of Italy) is not the United States.

Comment: @Ekadh Singh: As further sources, see the Forbes 400 list of US billionaires.  More than 2/3s of them are considered self-made, rather than having inherited wealth: https://www.forbes.com/sites/jonathanponciano/2020/09/08/self-made-score/?sh=5872444b41e4  At an extreme, of the 14 US Presidents since WWII, only 4 - Kennedy, the Bushes, & Trump - came from inherited wealth.  The rest came from poor to middle class backgrounds.

Comment: @jamesqf if the claim is "anyone can work their way up to be part of that modernized bourgeoise" then the counterexamples are the people who form the vast majority of the world's population who are not in fact capable of working their way up.  That it is possible for some people to work one's way up does not imply that anyone can.

Comment: @TedWrigley What you say about capitalist views on wages, benefits etc is true. However that can only be explained if they honestly believe what they are saying about trickle-down etc, because if that *doesn't* work then they are collectively strangling their own markets. Either way, its not about the Omniscient Council of Capitalist Vagueness where this discussion started. And I'm *not* a libertarian just because I don't believe in the Omniscient Council.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: So, even though I've explained how this isn't about some 'Council of Capitalists' but just a social effect, you're going to continue to pound on that 'CoC' straw-man argument because it's the only argument that produces the outcome you want, right? I know that's how this silly game is played, yes, but it still disappoints me every damned time...

Comment: @PaulJohnson: At any rate, you seem to be hung up on omniscience. Either it's the 'Omniscient Council of Capitalists' or it's perfectly omniscient individual capitalists who see the long-term relationship between wages and purchases, and the full, far-reaching implications of global labor interactions with perfect clarity. Unfortunately for your argument, capitalists (like most everyone else) are often short-sighted, greedy, callous, opinionated, bigoted, self-righteous, and/or etc. They want what's good for them in the short run, and don't mind stepping on others to get it.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: A world ruled by enlightened capitalists — just like a world ruled by an enlightened despot — might in fact be a very nice place; enlightened people **ought** to rule the world. But neither despotism nor capitalism attract the most enlightened among us, do they? Toss out that ideal and then ask yourself whether the result is still as pretty as the picture in your head.

Comment: @TedWrigley I'm calling a halt to this. You keep reading things I'm not saying.

Comment: @phoog: 1) Are we discussing the world's population, or people in relatively free economies such as the US?  In many places government and/or society make it difficult to almost impossible.  2) As with many things, there's a difference between being able to do something, and choosing to do it.  For instance, any reasonably healthy person can train to say run a 10K, but a lot of people choose not to.

Comment: @jamesqf: That is such an incredibly disingenuous comment. You seem to be suggesting that the only reason why a woman working in a Bangladeshi sweatshop, a latino picking fruits in a California orchard,  or the person packing your bags at the local grocery isn't as rich as (say) Mitt Romney is because they didn't *try* hard enough? Are we supposed to take that seriously?

Comment: @jamesqf even in the US and places like the US there is a large proportion of the population that is not capable of working their way up to the "modern bourgeoisie" for any of several reasons having nothing to do with choice.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley: First, I have said nothing about Bangladesh.  Second, I said nothing about being as rich as Mitt Romney, just being reasonably prosperous.  As for picking fruit in a California orchard, been there, done that.  While I've never personally bagged groceries (other than my own, as having someone bag your groceries seems to have gone out with 8-track tapes), I've certainly flipped burgers, pumped gas, put in 100+ hour weeks doing construction, scrubbed hotel toilets, and done other low-wage jobs.  Yet here I am :-)

Comment: @jamesqf: I don't actually know where you are (geographically or fiscally) so your personal anecdotes don't mean much to me. And the point isn't that one can become a comparatively wealthy proletarian: obviously people can rise within the working classes to very comfortable positions. The point is that entering into the capitalist class (where those like Mitt Romney, Bill Gates, Warren Buffet, and the Koch brothers reside) is impossible for most and requires something other than mere *trying* to achieve.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley : So what exactly do you mean by "capitalist class"?  Obviously, there can't be all that many people in the upper 0.0001% of say the Forbes 400.  (But note that both Gates & Buffet, like over 2/3 of the people on that list, didn't start life with parents on it.)  At the other extreme, anyone putting money into a 401k/IRA is a member of the capitalist class.

Comment: @jamesqf: Marxists would say that the capitalist class is those who own the means of production. In the modern world that has been deeply obfuscated, in part because of arcane chains of ownership through diversified corporate structures and in part because the concept of 'production' has shifted from Marx's straightforward material-industrial system to something based on the commodification of information. But (cont...)

Comment: @jamesqf: it's fairly simple to point at someone like Mitt Romney, whose entire business model is buying and selling ownership of companies (displacing workers, managers, etc by the boatload in the process). It's also worth noting that something well over fifty percent of the productive property in the world is owned by a vanishingly small number of people. It's interesting to see small numbers of people enter that group (though it's rare to see anyone leave across generations, even for the grossest incompetence), but that doesn't mean the group is accessible to just anyone, less everyone.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley: As I said, that capitalist class (in the US) includes anyone who has a 401k/IRA or similar retirement account.  (30% of US stock market.)  Other significant chunks are owned by pension plans and insurance companies: https://theirrelevantinvestor.com/2020/10/25/who-owns-the-stock-market/  Nearly half of the US market is owned by mutual funds, which are open to anyone with a small amount to invest.  (Much overlap with retirement accounts.)  So the "capitalist class" includes anyone who'd rather save than fritter away discretionary income on immediate pleasures.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley: Why do you keep harping on Mitt Romney?  He's not anywhere close to being on the Forbes 400 list, at least per Google.  That list is, by definition, a small number of people.  The same process takes place at all levels, so it's perfectly possible for someone (me, in fact) to go from field worker & homeless person to millionaire.

Comment: @james: You're confusing 'wealth' with 'control'. This isn't about the Forbes list; this is about who can deprive masses of people of livelihood at a whim. Your 401k is a nice perk, but it doesn't give you any particular control, and under the correct circumstances it can be pulled right out from under you without any warning or possibility of appeal. DOn't confuse being powerful with merely being rich.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley: Sorry, but it's seems to be you who have gone off on an unrelated "control" tangent.  As for having the 401k &c pulled out from under me, if we look at history we see that such things are pretty much done by socialist/Marxist governments.

Comment: @jamesqf: 401ks don't eist in socialist states — they are perks for laborers in capitalist systems — and thus historically they have only run into trouble when some owner or company decides to raid the funds for the owner's/company's benefit. An no, sorry, you don't get to frame the question so that it only allows for answers you like.

Comment: @Ted Wrigley: You're the one changing the question: when did it become about socialist states?  You may be correct about socialist states not having anything comparable to 401k/IRA plans: one reason most people in such states are doomed to remain poor.  As for employers raiding 401k plans, you really need to look into how they're set up.  Bottom line is that employers can't legally do that.  You may be thinking of old-style pension plans, and it was generally union bosses who did that.  See e.g. Jimmy Hoffa & the Teamsters - one reason we have 401k/IRA plans.

Comment: @jamesqf: it's pretty obvious that we're never going to agree on basic facts here, and ai'm pretty sure there's not much I can do about that: I'm philosophical, not ideological, so I have to maintain a certain relationship to both facts and reason. I suggest you stop arguing with me (which is fun, but not productive) and go ahead and write a comprehensive answer of your own. Either way, though, we should put a cork in this now.

Answer (score 34):

The core of Marx's critique of capitalism was that it would inevitably produce a vicious cycle in which the rich got richer and the poor got poorer. Marx had a deterministic vision of the process of history, in which impersonal economic processes like this would inevitably lead to certain results. As a result of this process, he believed that there would be a hollowing out of the social totem pole, with only two completely separated classes remaining: a few people at the top (call it class A), and all the rest at the bottom (B).

In order to describe this morbid end-stage of capitalism (which would then lead to the collapse of capitalism due to its own internal contradictions), he needed words for the classes A and B. Since the evolution of society had not yet reached the stage that he predicted, the existing vocabulary didn't actually have words to describe A and B. The society in which Marx lived had all kinds of social groupings, including hereditary nobles, small shopkeepers, sharecroppers, peasants, skilled tradesmen, factory workers, and so on.

However, Marx thought that class A would end up being one that believed in and consolidated the social and political values of the bourgeois society of his time, not the values of some other group such as the remnants of the old feudal nobility in Europe. Therefore he picked "bourgeois" as his label for the predicted-to-emerge class A. (For B he picked a label derived from ancient Roman society, proletariat.)

Answer (score 4):

> Why did Karl Marx use a term representing middle class instead of upper rich class? Any background?

Yeah, the background is time.

You are using modern definitions (which change a lot over time) and act like those were the same back when Marx wrote his book in 1867. That is AGES ago, and especially in regards to wealth, class or societal structures so much has changed.

Basically, when Marx wrote, the middle class were anyone rich or directly influential despite not being aristocratic (of noble birth). Since the aristocrat class is more or less irrelevant today and it is common today for non-aristocrats to hold at least some political power (democracy etc.) and capital, the formerly small "middle class" (Marx's burgeoisie) is nowadays split into what we know as the middle class today, and the upper class, the burgoisie in Marxist contexts (since the modern middle class does not hold the kind of power that the "middle class" at Marx's times held)

Answer (score -4):

Well first off, at least some (if not many) people who spend a lot of time arguing about this stuff on social media probably aren't rigorously using these concepts.

But the basic idea is extremely in-line with this quote:

> "First, I must confess that over the last few years I have been gravely disappointed with the white moderate. **I have almost reached the regrettable conclusion that the Negro's great stumbling block in the stride toward freedom is not the White Citizen's Council-er or the Ku Klux Klanner, but the white moderate who is more devoted to "order" than to justice**; who prefers a negative peace which is the absence of tension to a positive peace which is the presence of justice; who constantly says "I agree with you in the goal you seek, but I can't agree with your methods of direct action;" who paternalistically feels he can set the timetable for another man's freedom; who lives by the myth of time and who constantly advises the Negro to wait until a "more convenient season."

Letter from Birmingham Jail (ext)
By Rev. Martin Luther King, Jr., 16 April 1963

It is something you will commonly see in more, for a lack of a better word, revolutionary or "fringe" political ideologies -- more attacks and focus are placed on people closer to them in ideology than further.  The ones closer are seen as, in a sense, traitors, whereas the people opposite them are a lost cause.

There countless examples of this, but a clear current example is Liz Cheney being viscously attacked by Trump Republicans' for, in the words of ex House Speaker Boehner, "not being crazy".

TLDR: So in terms of your quote, the middle class is seen as the betrayer that protects the upper class.

Comment: This is more an extended comment than an answer.

Comment: While I generally agree with this idea overall, I don't think it applies in this case. As Ben and Ted's answers point out, Marx and Marxists use the word "bourgeoise" in a specific way that is different from the modern, commonplace definition of "middle class".